# laravel 5 where() not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have two tables, categories and subcategories, and each item in subcategories belongs to categories by foreign key "category_id".

i have two models one for categories and one for subcategories, and one controller.

my category model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Subcategory');
    }

}
```

subcategory model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'sub_category_name',
        'category_id'
    ];
}
```

and CategoriesController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Subcategory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    //return array of categories
    public function categories ()
    {

        $categories =  Category::where('category_name', '=', 'Construction Machines')->subcategories;
        return $categories;
    }
}
```

question is when i do Category::find()->subcategories i get the expected results. but when i use where(), it gives me Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$subcategories error

Comment: `$categories =  Category::with('subcategories')->where('category_name', '=', 'Construction Machines')->get();
        return $categories;`

Comment: also how can i access this variable in view without return make()? because the page i need this data on already is loaded, i need to populate drop down list with it?

Comment: @VishalDesai is it solved with futureweb comment or still?

Comment: yes, but I'm trying to access that return $categories inside my view.

Comment: you will need to return a view with the categories variable `return view('view.name',compact('categories'); ` then {{dd($categories)}} or <? print_r($categories); ?> in your view and it will output the data. You can access a specific value by `@foreach($categories as $category) {{$category->name}} @endforeach` assuming you are using blade and you have a name value in your categories collection.

Comment: I'm using blade template, and that is what i did, but i get Undefined variable: categories (View: /Users/babu/Sites/ito/resources/views/dash/add.blade.php)

Comment: how do i call that function from my view?

Comment: @futureweb if you leave answer I will vote it up.

Comment: yes leave answer and ill vote up, and regarding return issue I'm going to have to change the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, you will need to return a view with the categories variable

```
 return view('view.name',compact('categories');
```

then

```
  {{dd($categories)}}
```

or

```
 <? print_r($categories); ?>
```

in your view and it will output the data. You can access a specific value by

```
 @foreach($categories as $category) 
    {{$category->name}} 
 @endforeach
```

assuming you are using blade and you have a name value in your categories collection.